# Getting Laravel error

Tags: php, html

I am working with laravel i got an error while posting data , i created controlle, model and form every thing . I use resource controller and specify route but getting error which i gave here down at bottom of this page
Can someone help me, i tried so much change path, route and every thing but still could be able to solve this 
Thanks in advance

**My form**

```html
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        Create Aticle
      </div>
    <div class="panel panel-body">
      <form action="/l6/articles" class="form-group" method="POST" >

          {{ csrf_field()}}
              <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="" />
          <label for="content">Content</label>
            <textarea name="content" rows="4" cols="20" class="form-control"></textarea>

          <div class="checkbox">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="live">
                <input type="checkbox" name="live" >Live
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="post_on">Posted On</label>
                  <input type="datetime-local" name="post_on" value="" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Create</button>
      </form>

    </div
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

**My Controller**

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Article;
use Auth;

class ArticlesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('articles.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $article = new Article;
        $article->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $article->content =  $request->content;
        $article->live = (boolean)$request->live;
        $article->post_on = $request->post_on;
        $article->save();
      
    }

?>

Route is 
Route::resource('/articles', 'ArticlesController');
```

```html
(1/1) MethodNotAllowedHttpException
in RouteCollection.php (line 251)
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('GET', 'HEAD', 'POST'))
in RouteCollection.php (line 238)
at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('GET', 'HEAD', 'POST'))
in RouteCollection.php (line 176)
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request))
in Router.php (line 548)
at Router->findRoute(object(Request))
in Router.php (line 527)
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request))
in Router.php (line 513)
at Router->dispatch(object(Request))
in Kernel.php (line 176)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please share your routes.php.

If you are using the method Route::resource('articles','ArticlesController'), the route that calls the function create has to be like that http://project/articles/create

Comment: my create is function is working properly , but when i hit submit button there after i got error, mean not posting data into database instead it gives me error my route is like this

Comment: my Route is 
Route::resource('/articles', 'ArticlesController');

Comment: @Khalid try changing the route in your form, put action="/articles"

Comment: thanks but i tried it and all other ways I was thinking but it did not work for me, i really working on this from many many hours , but still stack at this error

Comment: @Khalid maybe you can change your route.php and using Route::controller instead Route::resource, to me is much more easy :).  https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#implicit-controllers